# Ubuntu - display red error message when cd into a certain directory

Tags: ubuntu

When ever a certain user is doing: `cd /var/www/*` I want to display a red message, "THIS IS PRODUCTION".

on any folder bellow /var/www/

Is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
PS1='$(if [[ $PWD == /var/www/* ]]; then echo -n "\[\033[01;31m\]THIS IS SPARTA\[\033[00m\]:"; fi; echo "\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$")'
```

For persistence... throw that in `~/.bashrc` or some such.

Comment: Wooow. amazing!!!

Comment: +1 for the example message. :)